# How to remove some characters without removing it in every case in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a dataset where I have grouped by a `Gene` column so rows are condensed to have multiple values. It looks like:

```
Gene     col1        col2        col3
Gene1    0.02, 0.3   ., ., .     0.2, 0.5
Gene2    1, .        ., ., ,     .
```

I am trying to clear all cases of `.,` so I can have just either empty cells or just the numeric values separated by commas (in a further step I will select the min or max value per gene and column out of the comma separated values I've stored in the cells)

For removing the `.,` I am trying:

```
data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {
  gsub(".,", "", x)
}))
```

But this is giving me:

```
Gene     col1        col2         col3
Gene1    0.02 0.3     .           0.2 0.5    #comma is now missing between my numbers
Gene2    1 .          .           .
```

I want to keep the commas between my numeric values in each cell - how can I do this? I thought using `gsub(".,", "", x)` would look specifically for  `.,` but I can see it hasn't.

I was also planning on using the same `gsub` code to replace the now singular fullstops I'm getting to be NA - will re-using my above code for this purpose be ok?

For full context, my real data is 200 columns by 37k rows - many of my columns have the `.,` included not just 3. Before running this `gsub` code above I am just reading in the file and first running:

`data <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ", "), by = Genes]`

Comment: `#comma is now missing between my numbers` Those aren't numbers, they are numeric characters.  If you want to act on them numerically you'll have to either split them in separate numeric columns, e.g. col1a, col1b or encode them into a single numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to modify your regular expression. I'm not the best at regular expressions, but this gets your desired output:

```
#your data    
data <- data.frame(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2"), 
                   col1 = c("0.02, 0.3", "1, ."),
                   col2 = c("., ., .", "., ., ,"),
                   col3 = c("0.2, 0.5", "."))

#the code you're looking for:
data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {
  gsub("\\.,|\\.$|\\,$|(, .$)", "", x)
}))
```

Output:

```
   Gene      col1 col2     col3
1 Gene1 0.02, 0.3      0.2, 0.5
2 Gene2         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
   col1 = c("1.2, 4.0", "1.7", "23, 9.0"),
   col2 = c("., .,", ".,", ".,")
)
```

Solution:

```
df <- sapply(df, function(x) gsub("(?<!\\d\\s)\\.,", "", x, perl = T))
```

This solution uses negative lookbehind ("match if you do not see ... on the left") in `(?<!\\d\\s)`; that is, the replacement of `.,` with nothing is implemented *only* if `.,` is preceded by a digit and a whitespace character.

```
df
     col1       col2
[1,] "1.2, 4.0" " " 
[2,] "1.7"      ""  
[3,] "23, 9.0"  ""
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with('col'), ~ str_remove_all(., '\\.,')))
```

-output

```
#  Gene      col1 col2     col3
#1 Gene1 0.02, 0.3    . 0.2, 0.5
#2 Gene2      1, .    ,        .
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
#Code
dfres <- as.data.frame(sapply(data, function(x) gsub('.,','',x,fixed = T)))
```

Output:

```
   Gene      col1 col2     col3
1 Gene1 0.02, 0.3    . 0.2, 0.5
2 Gene2      1, .    ,        .
```

Answer (score 0):

You see, `gsub` uses regex patterns, "." and "," are special characters if I'm not mistaken, so you have to escape it. The correct pattern for what you want should be:

```
gsub("\\.\\,", "", x)
```